# Difference between "acceptSelectedSuggestion" and "acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion" in VSCode keybinding config

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I'm configuring keybindings of Visual Studio Code. For accepting suggestions, two keybindings are set by default, but I have no idea why there are `acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion` and `acceptSelectedSuggestion` as they seem to cause the same effect. What is the difference?

```json
{ 
  "key": "shift+tab",
  "command": "acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion",
  "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus" 
},
{ 
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
  "when": "suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimentally, it affects what happens to the text to the right of the caret if the caret is in the middle of a word during completion.

- `acceptSelectedSuggestion` causes the text to the right of the caret to be *kept* after the suggestion is accepted.
- `acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion` causes the text to the right of the caret to be *removed* after the suggestion is accepted.

If you feel like further digging, the source code can be found in the following files:

- [`src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/browser/suggestController.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/browser/suggestController.ts)
- [`src/vs/editor/contrib/inlineCompletions/browser/suggestWidgetInlineCompletionProvider.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/inlineCompletions/browser/suggestWidgetInlineCompletionProvider.ts)