# Why does Tab accept suggestions and replace the following text, while Enter accepts and retains it in VS Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, autosuggest

I'm trying to select one of the suggestions IntelliSense suggests me using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. While using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key works as expected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> inserts the suggestion before the text and closes the quote breaking my json. How can I configure <kbd>Tab</kbd> to behave the same way as <kbd>Enter</kbd> does?

Expected behaviour with <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: expected]

Wrong behaviour with <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image: actual]

Probably related default options:

```
"editor.suggest.insertMode": "insert",
"[jsonc]":  {
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
                "strings": true
        },
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    },
"editor.tabCompletion": "off",
```

Looks like <kbd>Enter</kbd> follows custom rules for JSON with comments, but <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not.

Comment: @starball looks like the IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings extension messed things up. With default keybingings it works fine. So many broken extensions in Marketplace :(. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was found to be caused by the IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings extension. And looking under its hood, it's pretty simple why it happens. Look in its [package.json file](https://github.com/kasecato/vscode-intellij-idea-keybindings/blob/master/package.json) (its extension manifest), and look in the `contributes` > `keybindings` property. You'll see this:

```json
{
    "key": "enter",
    "mac": "enter",
    "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "acceptSuggestionOnEnter && suggestWidgetVisible && suggestionMakesTextEdit && textInputFocus",
    "intellij": "Choose Lookup Item"
},
{
    "key": "tab",
    "mac": "tab",
    "command": "acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion",
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus",
    "intellij": "Choose Lookup Item Replace"
},
```

See [Difference between "acceptSelectedSuggestion" and "acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion" in VSCode keybinding config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75403131/11107541), which explains that:

> - `acceptSelectedSuggestion` causes the text to the right of the caret to be *kept* after the suggestion is accepted.
> - `acceptAlternativeSelectedSuggestion` causes the text to the right of the caret to be *removed* after the suggestion is accepted.

Note: If you want to check if an extension is causing a specific behaviour, here's what you can do to troubleshoot: Does the behaviour happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.