# How can I get Atom-like autocomplete in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When auto-completing, most editors either overwrite the word your cursor is in front, or just insert the completion without touching any other text. Atom has a happy medium between the two that I really like, but is a bit hard to put into words. It basically replaces any part of the word that is a suffix of the completion. Let me give some examples, the pipe (`|`) is the cursor and in each example, we autocomplete "HelloWorld":

- `Hello|You` -> `HelloWorld|You`
- `Hello|World` -> `HelloWorld|`
- `Hello|InTheWorld` -> `HelloWorld|InTheWorld`
- `Hello|rld1234` -> `HelloWorld|1234`

I've found that this rarely gets it wrong, without me needing to think about whether I wanted to replace something or not. And having gotten used to it, I find both the other options (always replacing and never replacing) do something I didn't want often.

I'm finally looking at switching away from Atom. Is there a way to make autocomplete work in VS Code the way it does in Atom?

Comment: don't forget to leave a link here to your feature request issue ticket if you raise one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash / readline / inputrc, this feature (or something very similar to it)'s setting is called `skip-completed-text`. As far as my knowledge goes, VS Code just has a setting called `editor.suggest.insertMode`, which (at the time of this writing), only has `"insert"` (never replace anything) and `"replace"` (always replace the following text range- as defined by the language extension for the current language mode (or something like that)) as options (and [some associated keyboard shortcut binding points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75403131/11107541)).

So (and I hope I'm right about this- I'm not 100% confident), the correct next step if you really want such a feature is to [raise it as a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) to the VS Code maintainers, probably as a new value to the existing `editor.suggest.insertMode` setting. If you do that, make sure to describe in detail how it should behave (Ex. showing the example you've shown in your question post here). You'll need to get a certain number of thumbs up reactions within a certain time period if you want it to get added to the backlog, so I'd suggest to promote your feature request to your friends / peers / colleagues, and on dev platforms like [r/vscode](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode).

Comment: Good explanation of the situation. I might make a feature request at some point. I'm a bit hesitant because it's an absolute shame that feature requests are a popularity contest rather than being judged on their merits...